# Postgresql copy command error using WITH and AND

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have the following command where i am trying to copy a csv into a postgre table.

```
copy "SIS_student"(
            student_id, user_id, peims_id, district_id, prior_identifier, 
            first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex_code, race, date_of_birth, 
            birth_place, country_entry_date, address1, address2, address3, 
            city, state, zip, phone, email, status, campus_id_id, homeroom, 
            eco_dis_code, title1_pa_code, average_daily_attendance, ca_tech_ed_code, 
            bilingual_code, lep_code, esl_code, special_ed_code, gifted_tal_code, 
            at_risk_code, migrant_code, certification_date, graduation_date, 
            quartile, graduation_plan, class_rank, class_size, ranking_date, 
            gpa, nga, weighed_gpa, weighed_nga, peims_campus, next_yr_loc, 
            sumr_loc, c504, avid, last_update_date, last_updated_by, ethnicity_code, grade, 
            homeless, sept1_age, parental_permission, yrs_us_schools_text, 
            achievement_test_date, read_nce1, lang_nce1, eng_prof_test_date, 
            eng_prof_score, eng_prof_score_lvl, sp_prof_test_date, sp_prof_score, 
            sp_prof_score_lvl, peims_language, immigrant, date_entered_us_school, 
            grade_entered, years_in_us_schools, original_placement_date, 
            last_exit_date, parent_perm_date, ethnicity_race_code)
from '/home/abhishek/Downloads/HP/Student.csv' with delimiter ';' and NULL as 'NULL';
```

But i am getting a syntax error at AND. Where am i going wrong? The purpose i am doing this is because my DateTime fields are not taking NULL values from the csv even when i enabled NULL values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `and`. It is just a comma

```
with (delimiter ';', NULL 'NULL');
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: still throwing me this error:  syntax error at or near ","

Comment: @crozzfire Edited. There are parenthesis around the options.

Comment: @crozzfire And there is no `as`